# The object of a transitive verb

Tags: objects, transitive-verbs

I was simply wondering if the object of a transitive verb can come before the verb?
As in

- "Good luck," the man said to John.

Is "good luck" the object of "say" here?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: No: "the man said to John" is a kind of parenthetical. Note that objects are always noun phrases, never clauses.

Comment: Directly quoted speech is rather a special case, not the usual 'object of a verb' Does [this](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/grammar-pattern/v-with-quote_1) help?

Comment: Though some analyses differ, it's probably best to classify quotative verbs like _say, ask, reply, shout, sigh, whisper, smile, coo, smirk_ (when used with quotes) as a separate class, neither transitive nor intransitive.

Comment: Even in the embedded counterpart _The man said, "Good luck" to John_, "good luck" would still not be object of "said"; rather, the reported speech would be a complement of the reporting verb.

Comment: Here's a better example: *The ball I gave to John was round.* Unless you mean to ask specifically about speech. You need to clarify the exact focus of your question.

Comment: Yes, you can look at "quotative inversion" that way, as some traditional grammars do. The man said *what*? *Good luck*.  Also, in object questions, the object comes before the verb: *What did you eat?* (*What* is the object and *you* is the subject.)